# show pinned item at the very top of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a checkbox with the help of metabox for pinning news items, just can't keep last pinned item be at the very top of list, here is my code:

```
$today = date("Ymd");
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'news',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'meta_key' => 'pinned_news_item',
     'meta_value' => '1',
     'order'  => 'DESC',
     'orderby' => $today,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. Here is a code that worked for me:

```
$args_meta = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'pinned_news_item',
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1' 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try by editing your query:

$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'news',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
      meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'key' => 'pinned_news_item',
                         'value' => '1',
              )
          ),
     'order'  => 'DESC',
     'orderby' => $today,
);

Reference: http://www.happiweb.net/2015/05/code-wordpress-thuong-dung.html
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't help anyways thanks, I posted my answer, after many searches I found solution @happweb.net